# How to Create a Pop-Up Message (or Something Similar) When Blender Is Frozen

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, tracking

I have created a Blender addon that requires a lot of computational power and takes some time to process. It is an automatic camera tracking addon. The only thing the user needs to do is enter their image sequence name and click the "Start autotracking" button to then be treated to a perfectly tracked scene (the user chooses the maximum solve error they need).

For more details, go to Blender Market and search for the FlaxTrax addon.

The addon works wonderfully, and many people like it. However, when the addon is loading, the user only sees Blender frozen and needs to wait until it is finished loading, which takes around 1-25 minutes depending on the footage type.

Is there any way I can print out a message on a pop-up window or similar that describes for the user on which step it is on, etc., even if Blender is frozen?